# How do I set the data from the dataset to a combolist in c1flexgrid?

Tags: c#, dataset, componentone, c1flexgrid

How do I set the data from the dataset to a `combolist` in `c1flexgrid`?

I've tried this:

```
GridSales.Cols(5).ComboList = row("Unit")
```

but it doesn't show all data from the dataset in the combolist of grid?

Comment: i wanna get all data in the dataset in grid as a combolist.

Comment: If you use WinForm you can generate a ComboBox separately and set this as the editor of the specific cell into c1FlexGrid, that is, c1FlexGrid.Cells [0] .Editor = comboBox1;
This work fine but this implies generate separate control and fill this control manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways.

***Option 1***

You can create a string based on you values like

```
var str = "value1|Value2|Value3";

GridSales.Cols(5).AllowEditing = true;
GridSales.Cols(5).ComboList = str;
```

***Option 2***

You can create a dropdown form using `C1DropDown`

```
GridSales.Cols(5).Editor = DropDownControl;
```

Also since this is a third-party control, you can directly ask question on their support site where you have more chances of getting answers. Have a look [here](http://our.componentone.com/groups/)